# PyCharm closes external GraphWin window immediately

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, zelle-graphics

Following a beginners Python3 tutorial, I am supposed use the graphics module to generate an external GraphWin() window and keep it until win.close() is initiated.
At the moment I don't wish to run win.close() and want to keep it open, but PyCharm's "process finished with exit code 0" shuts it off automatically. How can i solve this?

thank you in advance!!

Comment: could you add some code to reproduce this issue ?

Comment: Can you please add relevant code snippets from your project? Also, what graphics module are you programming with? It is difficult making suggestions about specifics if these are missing.

Answer (score 0):

The [Overview](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/node2.html) at the very beginning of the Zelle graphics documentation explains this:

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin("My Circle", 100, 100)
    c = Circle(Point(50,50), 10)
    c.draw(win)
    win.getMouse() # pause for click in window
    win.close()

main()
```

It's the combination of:

```
win.getMouse() # pause for click in window
win.close()
```

That holds the window open until the the user clicks on it.  Primitive but effective.  I checked and it seems to work fine with PyCharm.